# google maps: fire event when panTo loads completely

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm panning to a nearby location but the `panTo` function often jumps there since it's not within the current bounds. Sometimes when I do this, the map has to load imagery because I haven't been there yet, but sometimes it loads instantly from the cache because I have.

I want to fire another function immediately once the map is done loading (if I fire it while it's loading, the JS lags, which for my purposes isn't acceptable). Is there an eventListener or something that I can listen for, or a callback function that I could use? Also, Merry Christmas :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of events that are fired on the `Map` object are listed at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map.

Your best bets for what your describing are likely `idle` ("This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.") and/or `tilesloaded` ("This event is fired when the visible tiles have finished loading.").

If those can't be used to determine when the tiles are done loading, you are probably out of luck as far as simple and obvious solutions go.